# Getting error while installing npm modules on host system via vagrant

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, vagrant

I am accessing ubuntu Virtual Machine from my host via vagrant and facing issues in npm module installations.

Scenario 1:  When I try to do npm install directly on my ubuntu VM via vagrant I get error like :

***npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/home/vagrant/workspace/TruckLease-network/node_modules/bn.js/package.json.1931599852' ->  '/home/vagrant/workspace/TruckLease-network/node_modules/bn.js/package.json'***

Also gets multiple warnings for various modules giving same error - text file is busy.
I tried adding below to my vagrant file but did not work :

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|         v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]   end

Scenario 2 :  Then I tried to run 'npm install' on windows system directly , it worked with few warnings. Then I did run npm server to launch the application , that also run successfull. But when I hit the application with a get request I get Error :

***Original error: Cannot find module '/home/vagrant/workspace/TruckLease-network/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'***

Please suggest where should I exactly run 'npm install' and let me know if there are any pre or post steps for running npm install.

Thanks,
Kalyani

Answer (score 0):

If running npm install on a windows host and then running on Vagrant, you might try `npm install --no-bin-links`